# border in listview not visible in android emulator

Tags: android, xml

I have been trying to style my `listview` item in my `mainactivity.xml` for a note application. So far i have successfully implemented a background color for each `listview` item.
I then tried to show a left vertical border also for each item. It is visible in the android studio design view but is not visible when i run on the emulator. Am i getting something wrong? Am using a `View`widget for my left vertical border.

```
MainActivity.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_listview"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_listview_margin"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:divider="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

listview_component.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <View
// here is where am trying to implement a left vertical border for each list view item
        android:id="@+id/verticallineview"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_note_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/lightBlack" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_note_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text=""
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_note_content_preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
android:textColor="@color/black"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your parent layout in the component xml with orientation horizontal and create another linear layout with vertical orientation inside it to place the three text views

For reference try this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<View
    android:id="@+id/verticallineview"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_note_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="asdasdaasdasdasdasd"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_note_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="aasdasdasdasdasdad"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_note_content_preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```